# How do applications manage front end error tracking?

Tags: angular, flask, design-patterns, error-handling

So we are facing difficulties in tracking, detecting errors on the client-side of our application. Currently, there is no error tracking done whats so ever. Here is a brief about a solution that I thought about. I want to know what are industry standards and practices and what the topics I can explore with regard to this?

My solution:

> 1. After every unit piece of the controller is executed, if there are any errors, ping a service that will collect the error and write it to
>      the backend server. The written error logs can be tracked and
>      monitored.
> 2. I am worried that as the product scales and the number of users grows, this approach will generate too many pings to the backend and
>      can potentially bring many servers down(being pessimistic :). So we
>      can write it to local storage or indexedDB and periodically initiate a
>      data collection service that will collect this data and writes it to
>      the backend.

PS: we have error tracking, handling and monitoring feature in the backend that does the heavy lifting. However, some errors just get past this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need to trace step by step every user's activities, in fact you need to have a log service in backend and call it internally in every api that user sends request to it, or in every important activity. just avoid of sending log request to the server.